# Can I generate and store keys on my Yubico?

Tags: encryption, key-management, digital-signature, yubikey

Its a simple question but there's no answer in the Yubico's website

When I recive a Yubico (from the Yubico 4 series), I know I can sign code, for example. But how is the key inside it generated? Is it generated on the manufacturing process? Can I generate a key in mmy computer and upload to it?

Comment: Can you specify which key you're referring to? The key used in U2F, or a PGP key?

Comment: The keys in the 4 series are all capable of the same things, which includes PGP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## U2F

The keys used in U2F are generated by the device it self, you can't do it yourself. [Yubico's Developer webpage](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Key_generation.html) explain it very clearly. For short, take a look the graph below.[image: U2F Private Key Generation Description]

Device Secret is generated in manufacture phrase. As far as I know, this secret can't changed by a software tweak. AppID is equal to web service URL. At the time of generation, an integrated RNG will generate a Nonce, feed in to a HMAC-SHA256 with AppID, keyed with the device secret, the output is the private key. Then feed the private key and the AppID into the HMAC function again, concatenate the output and the nonce, which becomes the key handle. Public key is generate by the private key, and sent it with the key handle to the web service.

## X.509/PIV

This is the part about code signing and the key to do. Yes, you can generate a private key on your own machine and upload it to the Yubikey. Take a look [Yubico's PIV explanation](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/). Especially articles under `Introduction/Certificate slots`, `Tools/YubiKey PIV Manager(if you use Windows)` and `Guides`.

## OpenPGP

Yubico is a bit lack of explaining this part, so I found a great [GitHub repo](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide) contributed by [drduh](https://github.com/drduh) where it contain a full explanation how to use OpenPGP with Yubikey.